# Xamarin.iOS - find UIPickerView

Tags: xamarin.ios

In an attempt to get a better solution to my problem selecting a Picker on iOS for UITests (see thread [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/370177#Comment_370177) ), I want to write a 'backdoor' method which selects the appropriate UIPicker item programmatically.

To do this, I need to be able to find the UIPicker which is being displayed. However, I'm having trouble finding it! Iterating through all UIViews on all UIWindows.

My code for finding the View is below:

```
           UIView viewFound = null;
           foreach (var currentWindow in UIApplication.SharedApplication.Windows)
           {
               viewFound = FindViewOfClass(currentWindow, typeof(UIPickerView),level);
               if (viewFound != null)
               {
                   break;
               }
           }
```

...

```
   private static UIView FindViewOfClass(UIView view, Type classToFind, int level)
   {

       string message = $“{classToFind} - {level} View: + {view.GetType().ToString()}“;
       Console.WriteLine(message);
       if (view.GetType() == classToFind)
       {
           level--;
           return view;
       }

       foreach (var item in view.Subviews)
       {
           level++;
           return FindViewOfClass(item, classToFind,level);
       }

       return null;
   }
```

But I'm not seeing the UIPickerView - even when it's definitely displayed on the screen. The above code does work when searching for other Views.

So the question is - is there a better way of finding a UIView on the current page? I couldn't find a built-in method.

Note that this is in a Xamarin.Forms app on iOS - so there are several extra UI artefacts present (in terms of the Views for implementing the iOS renderer) - however, ultimately the Picker is implemented as a UIPickerView (I can see it by using the 'tree' command and app.repl() in UITest).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @LandLu on the Xamarin forums the solution is:

You should obtain the current view controller first. Then iterate the subview to get your picker renderer.
Here is my dependency service for you referring to:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(FindViewClass))]
namespace Demo.iOS
{
    public class FindViewClass : IFindView
    {
        public void FindViewOfClass()
        {
            UIViewController currentViewController = topViewController();
            getView(currentViewController.View);
        }

        List<PickerRenderer> pickerList = new List<PickerRenderer>();
        void getView(UIView view)
        {
            if (view is PickerRenderer)
            {
                pickerList.Add((PickerRenderer)view);
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (UIView subView in view.Subviews)
                {
                    getView(subView);
                }               
            }
        }

        UIViewController topViewController()
        {
            return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController);
        }

        UIViewController topViewControllerWithRootViewController(UIViewController rootViewController)
        {
            if (rootViewController is UITabBarController)
            {
                UITabBarController tabbarController = (UITabBarController)rootViewController;
                return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(tabbarController.SelectedViewController);
            }
            else if (rootViewController is UINavigationController)
            {
                UINavigationController navigationController = (UINavigationController)rootViewController;
                return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(navigationController.VisibleViewController);
            }
            else if (rootViewController.PresentedViewController != null)
            {
                UIViewController presentedViewController = rootViewController.PresentedViewController;
                return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(presentedViewController);
            }
            return rootViewController;
        }
    }
}
```

Once I've done that, I can select the index/item I want via the Element property of the Renderer.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Set the  property **Tag** when you init the pickerview.

```
pickerView.Tag = 1000;

View.AddSubview(pickerView);
```

And you and get it by method **ViewWithTag**

```
var picker =  View.ViewWithTag(1000);
```

View here is the subview of your pickerView.

Comment: Thanks - but the pickerView is being added by Xamarin.Forms, so we can't set the Tag.

Comment: You can use the customRenderer

Comment: Yes, but we don't want to have to use a customRenderer just to be able to run UITests against the app. I've got a good solution from LandLu on the Xamarin forums - I'll post it shortly.